# Highstock display two horizontal rules

Tags: highcharts

Hi i am using charts from this site http://www.highcharts.com/. For stockChart I set option `crosshairs: [true, true]` to display both horizontal and verticall line where is my mouse. My questin is , is it possbile to display two horizontall lines lying out from each other by defined spread like it is in MT4 ? [image]

Comment: did you try plot lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use addPlotLine() and try to add new in each move, or try to use Renderer path http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path() which allows to draw line in any place.